# How to access ImageButton from fragment in fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using ViewPager and loading multiple fragment in Fragment Activity using **FragmentPage Adapter**. I want to access a fragment which contains an **ImageButton**. Can any one help me to access **Imagebutton** from fragment in fragment activity?

Here is my code :

**Fragment Activity**

```
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_gallery);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (CustomPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

       pagerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tour_pager_lay);
       mPageControl = (PageControl)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_pager);
       mPageControl.addPagerControl(3);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.landing_logo);
            case 1:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.welcome_postit);
            case 2:

                return new LoginFragment();
            case 4:
                return new RegisterFragment();

            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your ImageButton is on your RegisterFragment, then you can do:

```
RegisterFragment tmp = ((RegisterFragment) ((MyAdapter) mPager.getAdapter()).instantiateItem(mPager, 4));

//your ImageButton should be public or you can create a getter or something, I assume that it's public
tmp.imageButton.setText("foo");
```

Comment: It gives me nullPointerException  :(

Comment: Yes I see, it's because you have an error in your code and I didn't see it. It's in your adapter in getItem method. You have `case 4:  return new RegisterFragment();` but you have only 3 pages so it should be `case 3:...`. And in my code you should change parameter in `instantiateItem(mPager,4)` to `instantiateItem(mPager,3)`.

Comment: So what exactly error do you have? (note: this code should be called after setting an adapter to ViewPager). And you have another error: your getCount returns 3 and you have 4 fragments in your adapter...

Comment: NullPointerException at imageButton line

Comment: As I said (in my updated previous comment) you have some errors in your code. Also try to firstly swipe to your fragment with imageButton and then call this method. In other words: viewPager keeps only current and two adjacent fragments in memory by default so if you have 4 fragment and you want access 4th fragment when you are seeing 1st then 4th is not created yet. You can change number of living fragments by: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29